# No Custom Events in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Trying to create custom event in Application Insights but it doesn't show up on Azure Portal. All other events like requests, dependencies, exception are visible.

I have tried in dotnet core and can see following in debug log, but still no event in portal, even custom event table is empty:

```
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.<instrumentkey>.Event","time":"2019-12-05T19:16:34.1373921Z","iKey":"<instrument key>","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"<role>","ai.session.id":"<session>","ai.user.id":"<user>","ai.operation.id":"<operation>","ai.operation.parentId":"|<some ids>","ai.operation.name":"GET /auth/login","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"dotnetc:2.11.0-21474","ai.internal.nodeName":"<subscription>"},"data":{"baseType":"EventData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"SAML_Authentication_Initiated","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Local"}}}}
```

Tried from javascript as well, can see following successful post request in browser console:

```
POST https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track

[{"time":"2019-12-05T19:00:21.781Z","iKey":"<instrumentkey>","name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.<instrumentkey>.Event","tags":{"ai.user.id":"<user>","ai.session.id":"<session>","ai.device.id":"browser","ai.device.type":"Browser","ai.operation.name":"/public","ai.operation.id":"<operationid>","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"javascript:2.3.1"},"data":{"baseType":"EventData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"CustomEvent","properties":{},"measurements":{}}}}]
```

*Response*

```
{"itemsReceived":1,"itemsAccepted":1,"errors":[],"appId":"<application id>"}
```

Not sure how much time Azure needs to process custom event or should I create support ticket or something is wrong at my end.

Comment: have you tried using TelemetryClient trackEvent?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics

Comment: yeah, using TelemtryClient

Comment: Most custom events come in within 5mins. When you say you've looked in the portal have you actually tried querying inside app insights itself?

Comment: just checked, all custom events are now visible. Must be some Azure thing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application insights usually takes 3-5 minutes before data begins appearing in the portal, see the **Note** section of this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/dotnetcore-quick-start#configure-app-insights-sdk).

If you worry about the data is missing, you can use [Flush()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#flushing-data) method.

And if it always takes more than 5 minutes before data appearing in portal, you should consider [opening a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get professional help.