# QnAMaker Telemetry customevents data is null

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to use QnAMaker's Application Insights for logging in the Azure Portal. I've noticed that all of the data associated with the customEvents field in each table is null:

[Query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rulbu.png)

Here is my query that I'm using in the query editor in Azure, in the Application Insight's log:

```
requests |project
ActivityId = customDimensions.activityId, 
ActivityType = customDimensions.activityType,
ChannelId = customDimensions.channelId  , 
ConversationId = session_Id ,
ReplyActivityId = customDimensions.replyActivityId , 
FromId = customDimensions.fromId , 
Locale = customDimensions.locale  ,
RecipientId = customDimensions.recipientId,  
Speak = customDimensions.speak ,  
Text =    customDimensions.text,
EventName = name, 
Time = timestamp, 
Date = timestamp,
DialogInstanceId = customDimensions.InstanceId,
DialogId = customDimensions.DialogId  , 
DialogStepName = customDimensions.StepName,
Luis_ApplicationId = customDimensions.applicationId,
Luis_Intent = customDimensions.intent,
Luis_IntentScore = customDimensions.intentScore,
Luis_Entities = customDimensions.entities,
Luis_Question = customDimensions.question,
Luis_SentimentLabel = customDimensions.sentimentLabel,
Luis_SentimentScore = customDimensions.sentimentScore,
QnA_KnowledgeBaseId = customDimensions.knowledgeBaseId,
QnA_Answer = customDimensions.answer,
QnA_ArticleFound = customDimensions.articleFound,
QnA_OriginalQuestion = customDimensions.originalQuestion,
QnA_Question = customDimensions.question,
QnA_QuestionId = customDimensions.questionId,
QnA_Score = customDimensions.score,
QnA_UserName = customDimensions.username,
User_City = client_City, 
User_State = client_StateOrProvince, 
User_Country = client_CountryOrRegion,
Feedback_Value = customDimensions.Feedback,
Feedback_Comment = customDimensions.Comment,
Feedback_Tag = customDimensions.Tag
```

All of the customDimensions.____ data is null. How can I adjust my QnAMaker code to log this data?

Here is where the QnAMaker is being instantiated:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class BotServices : IBotServices
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly IBotTelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public BotServices(IConfiguration configuration, IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;

            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            QnAMakerService = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
            {
                KnowledgeBaseId = configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
                EndpointKey = configuration["QnAAuthKey"],
                Host = GetHostname(configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"])
            },
            null,
            httpClient,
            _telemetryClient);
        }

        public QnAMaker QnAMakerService { get; private set; }

        private static string GetHostname(string hostname)
        {
            if (!hostname.StartsWith("https://"))
            {
                hostname = string.Concat("https://", hostname);
            }

            if (!hostname.EndsWith("/qnamaker") && !hostname.Contains("/v5.0"))
            {
                hostname = string.Concat(hostname, "/qnamaker");
            }

            return hostname;
        }
    }
}
```

And [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry-qnamaker?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) is the tutorial that I followed.

Comment: To use `customDimensions` in QnAMaker, you can refer to [Schema of Bot Analytics Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry-analytics-queries?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#schema-of-bot-analytics-instrumentation).

Comment: You can also refer to similar issues [No Custom Events in Application Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59202065/no-custom-events-in-application-insights), [BotTelemetry not storing any details in Application Insights](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/3725) and [Missing QnA Maker Insights Telemetry](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/3447)

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this issue is "Application insights usually takes 3-5 minutes before data begins appearing in the portal."

If you are worrying about the data is missing, you can use Flush() method.

If this is not your case or it takes longer time for you to see the data, I would highly recommend you to create a support ticket. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request